# ¿cómo desarrollar un sistema de opciones horizontalmente tipo slide desde botones?

Tags: javascript, html, css

se solicita crear un sistema de selección entre varias opciones que formateen el sitio según la selección, la verdad no sé por donde empezar, intenté hacerlo con input pero solo encuentro recursos con number, o el de texto solo me cambia el texto del input en una opción, estos son los ejemplos de lo que intenté pero no me sirve

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dGWP

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792585/change-value-of-input-field-onclick

[image: por medio de los botones menos o más, se cambia el tamaño de fuente en la web, lo mismo sucedería con el tipo de fuente]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que has intentado y explicar más detalladamente lo que debes hacer.

Comment: hola, no he intentado ningún código, lo que he hecho, es analizar los códigos de los enlaces que publiqué, pero no me sirven porque el primero, solo es para input de tipo number, y el otro, si hace el cambio del texto en el input pero solo una vez por botón, lo que requiero, basado en la imagen, es que al hacer clic en los botones, las opciones cambien y con base a la selección, yo pueda generar una clase en la etiqueta body para poder afectar el tamaño de la fuente en la web y el tipo de fuente.

Answer (score 1):

Es interesante lo que intentas hacer.

Lo primero que necesitas es capturar los cambios en estos controles independiente de lo que hagas una vez que tengas dichos valores. Es por esto que por ejemplo, simples opciones tales como 1,2 y 3 te sirven como para empezar.

Si logras crear un elemento que muestre la opción actual y botones que te permitan cambiar dicho valor, tendrás la mitad del trabajo duro.

¿qué hacer con estos valores?

Bueno, puedes desarrollar una función que en base al valor actual decida que clase insertar al body de la página por ejemplo.

Espero que te sirva!